# replace certain field in every line using awk

Tags: awk

I want to replace e certain field in every line with a given value

input

```
field1:field2:field3:field4
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
1111:2222:3333:4444
```

desired output

```
   field1:test:field3:field4
   aaaa:test:cccc:dddd
   1111:test:3333:4444
```

```
awk '{print $1, "test, $3, $4}' inputfile
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, to avoid downvotes and close votes(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: What stops you from doing that? Use an appropriate option to define a colon as a field separator first. Then for each row (except possibly the first one) substitute the desired value in a pre-determined field, then output the modified row.

Comment: Hint: `$2 = "test"` will replace field 2.

Comment: Nice approach, but not true. This could not work due to unbalanced double quotes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 His attempt was the last line of the question. It just wasn't formatted so you could see it.

Comment: The code you posted contains an extremely obvious syntax error. Try fixing that and  then tell us if you still have a problem.

Comment: @Barmar, sure Barmar, I had already voted to reopen this question hours back, only 1 vote is pending to re-open it.

Comment: If `$2` is not equal to `"test"` then `$2="test"`. With `awk`:  `awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":" } $2 != "test" {$2="test"} 1' file`

Comment: @CarlosPascual You do not need the condition here. :)

Comment: @CiaPan Ok, but just in case it appears a "test" in a row...

Comment: @CarlosPascual Then you just replace `"test"` with `"test"` :) and the output is still correct. It's just a matter of balancing between the code readability and efficiency. However, in regards of efficiency, it's not that clear which is the greater cost: doing additional test on every row 'just in case', when 'the case' happens rarely, or doing unnecessary replacement if it happens more often. It depends on input data and on the efficiency of both operations inside awk.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `FS` and `OFS` variables to `:`, they default to whitespace. Then you can replace field 2 by assigning to `$2`.

You also had a mismatched double quote.

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '{$2 = "test"; print}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of possible answers:

```
BEGIN { FS = ":"; OFS=":" };{$2 = "test"; print}
```

First define that a colon is a field separator for input data (`FS`) and for output data (`OFS`), then for each line substitute `"test"` for a second field and output the resulting line.

You can test it e.g. here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_awk_online.php

Answer (score 1):

Or saving yourself a few extra characters ;)

```
awk '{$2 = "test"};1' FS=':' OFS=':' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {print $1, "test", $3 ,$4}' file
```

Answer (score -3):

```
cat input |tr ':' ' ' |awk '{print $1,"test",$3,$4}' |tr ' ' ':'
```

Comment: How about data containing some spaces somewhere between colons (e.g. `Little Deer:Old Shatterhand:Sky Hawk:Singing Creek`)...?

Comment: i needed it for this specific example and it works

Comment: For _this specific example_ you coul just print `"   field1:test:field3:field4\n   aaaa:test:cccc:dddd\n   1111:test:3333:4444"` and not bother about input data and awk....

Comment: Even though this does what you want (and you're happy w/ the shortcoming CiaPan pointed out) - **4** processes where one would suffice?

Comment: sorry, my bad, specific example as in format, not only 3 lines( there are thousands of lines). There must be more elegant solutions but i'm not the sharpest tool in the shed and as long as it does what i need i'll take it

Comment: Possibly this is a solution for _your real-life problem_ but this is not an answer for your StackOverflow question. The question is _'[How to] replace certain field in every line using awk'_ and you did not do it with `awk`, but rather with two `tr` and `awk`. Which is an answer to 'How to (...) with standard Linux command-line tools, *including* `awk`.